# adding randomly generated values in increasing order

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I want to add the randomly generated values in increasing order instead of fixed `0.2` and `0.5` value inside `if else` statement.How to do that can anybody guide me? Thanks in advance.

My code is

```
N=10
dta=[]
x=0.0
for i in range(N):
    dta.append(x)

    if(i<5):
        x=x+0.2  #here instead of 0.2 randomly generated data in range 0.1 to 0.2
                 #should be added( example it may be 0.15,0.16....)
    else:
        x=x+0.5  #here instead of 0.5 randomly generated data in range 0.3 to 0.5
                 #should be added
print(dta)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
import random
N=10
dta=[]
x=0.0
for i in range(N):
    dta.append(x)

    if(i<5):
        x += random.uniform(0.1, 0.2)
    else:
        x += random.uniform(0.3, 0.5)
print(dta)
```

Sample Output:

```
[0.0, 0.13515152101736566, 0.2866133692895604, 0.4608222800319004, 0.6003500994767033, 0.7898596366391699, 1.2677308143972574, 1.571917695358207, 1.8899333979603337, 2.2967764098732637]
```

**UPDATE**:

To have the values themselves be in the range `0.1, 0.2` or `0.3, 0.5` and in increasing order, as indicated in OP's comments, you can do this:

```py
import random
N=10
dta = sorted([random.uniform(*(0.1, 0.2) if i < 5 else (0.3, 0.5)) for i in range(N)])
print(dta)
```

Sample output:

```
[0.10928830948278306, 0.13885822930882388, 0.15861800478212257, 0.16539989224271684, 0.18145832131929895, 0.34643148884688224, 0.3570560993108919, 0.44518489503000336, 0.48017733976314136, 0.4992591196660774]
```

If you prefer an easier-to-read approach, this does the same thing:

```py
import random
N=10
dta=[]
for i in range(N):
    if(i<5):
        x = random.uniform(0.1, 0.2)
    else:
        x = random.uniform(0.3, 0.5)
    dta.append(x)
dta.sort()
print(dta)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Updated my answer to sort. For your reference, docs on sorting in python are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).